# How do you go about refreshing content inside a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, refresh

I have several random variables that are being input into a modal from JavaScript, these consist of either numbers or strings.

Is there a way to have a "refresh" button to re-run the scripts to pull new random variables into the modal without closing the modal and re-opening it.

Currently this is being input into the modal:

```
    document.getElementById("randomScenario").addEventListener("click", Fullscenario); 
function Fullscenario() {
    document.getElementById("map-1-initialVelocity").innerHTML = window[velocities[randomUrban]].toFixed(2) + " kmh<sup>-1</sup>";
    document.getElementById("map-1-ylPhase").innerHTML = window[ypUrban[randomYpUrban]].toFixed(1) + " s";
    document.getElementById("map-1-rlPhase").innerHTML = window[ipUrban[randomIpUrban]].toFixed(1) + " s"; 
    document.getElementById("map-1-rtRandom").innerHTML = window[driverReaction[randomRt]].toFixed(2) + " s";
    document.getElementById("map-1-tireCondition").innerHTML = tires[tireCondition]; 
    document.getElementById("map-1-weatherCondition").innerHTML = coldClimates[randomTireCold];
    document.getElementById("map-1-carLength").innerHTML = carLength.toFixed(1);  
}
```

If I have a refresh button on the modal, what syntax do I require at the HTML side and JavaScript side to refresh these scenarios without opening and closing the modal?

Thanks kindly for your help.

Comment: Wrap that same code that you have in a function and execute it again!

Comment: I tried that - maybe I did it wrong. But I couldn't seem to get it to work. A few things crossed my mind. Firstly, it is one of the modal buttons that I want to use as a refresh. 

<button type="button" id="refreshScenario" class="btn btn-danger">Refresh</button>

And then have an event listener for that click. 

document.getElementById("randomScenario").addEventListener("click", Fullscenario);
document.getElementById("refreshScenario").addEventListener("click", FullscenarioX);  

Then would I just have:
function fullScenarioX () {
function Fullscenario() {
xyz }
}

Answer (score 0):

**somewhere inside modal HTML:**

```
<button onclick="Fullscenario()">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I think I tried that already and it didn't work from the modal. The button does nothing. I'll try again and see if I got something wrong somewhere, but that was how I thought it might work.

Comment: Sadly, as easy as this option sounds, it just does not work :(

Comment: Please, give more explanation and code snippets to get your problem solved.

Comment: In the end I decided I did not need to refresh the modal at all. I decided to go with using innerHTML DOM modifications to change what needed to be changed. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you are right! your function is already doing this. As many times you call your function, the DOM will be modified each time, because of innerHTML.